# Configure Prometheus for monitoring multiple microservices

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, prometheus, monitoring

I want to monitor a `Spring Boot` Microservices application running on `Docker-Compose` with about 20 microservices with `Prometheus` and `Grafana`.

What is the best approach:
1- Having one job with multiple targets for each microservice?

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'services-job'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['service-one:8080']
        labels:
          group: 'service-one' 
      - targets: ['service-two:8081']
        labels:
          group: 'service-two'
```

2- Having multiple jobs with single target for each service?

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'service-one-job'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['service-one:8080']
        labels:
          group: 'service-one'
  - job_name: 'service-two-job'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['service-two:8081']
        labels:
          group: 'service-two'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you group your targets by job has nothing to do with the number of endpoints to scrape.

You need to group all the targets with the same *purpose* in the same job. That's exactly what the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) says :

> A collection of instances with the same purpose, a process replicated for scalability or reliability for example, is called a job.